# Same user added more than once in Database

Tags: php, facebook

I'm new to PHP and I've been baffled by the following problem. When a facebook user logs in , the user is added to the database. However, when the same user logs in again it should print out 'Username already exists' but instead it's inserting the same user into the database again. How do i Fix it? Any help is appreciated

```
        <?php 
          echo "<p> Hello World!</p>";

        // php 5.3 and up can throw an error if this is not set  
        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");


        // much of the example code on the web forgets to include these HttpClients, for some reason
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );

        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

        // This one is also often left out
        require_once( '../docs/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');

        // store your $HOSTNAME, $APPID and $SECRET in this file:
        require_once( '../docs/my_app_credentials.php' );

        use Facebook\FacebookSession;
        use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
        use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
        use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
        use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
        use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
        use Facebook\GraphObject;

        session_start();

        // init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($APPID,$SECRET);

        // login helper with uri
        $PAGENAME="page2.php";
        $REDIRECT_URL="http://".$HOSTNAME.'/'.$PAGENAME;

        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $REDIRECT_URL );
        try {
            echo "<p> about to try to get session: the helper variable: </p>";
            $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        //  echo "<p> the session variable:</p>";
        //  var_dump($session);
            } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
          // When Facebook returns an error
          echo "<p> There was a facebook request exception</p>";
        } catch( \Exception $ex ) {
          echo "<p> There was a validation failure</p>";
          var_dump($ex);

          // When validation fails or other local issues
        }
          echo "<p> 'get session' block now completed...</p>";

        // see if we have a session
        if ( isset( $session ) ) {
          echo "<p> Now try to get a graph node</p>";

          // graph api request for user data
          $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
          $response = $request->execute();
          // get response
          $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

          // print data
          echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );


          $FBID=$graphObject->getProperty('id');
          $FIRSTNAME=$graphObject->getProperty('first_name');
          $SECONDNAME=$graphObject->getProperty('last_name');
          $TOKEN=$_GET['code'];

          //write code to check if current user is in database
          //if not add them to database
          //finally, give link to page3.php which removes them (user) from database.
          $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
          $query = "SELECT FBID FROM USERS WHERE FBID='$FBID'";

          $result = $con->query($query);

          if (!$result)
          {
              echo "Username already exists";
          }
          else
          {


           $con->query("INSERT INTO USERS (FBID,FIRSTNAME,SECONDNAME,TOKEN) VALUES ('$FBID','$FIRSTNAME','$SECONDNAME','$TOKEN')");
            echo"user inserted";
          }

        } else {
          // show login url
          echo 'No session was set. Try logging in again by clicking here: <a href="' . "page1.php". '">Login</a>';
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: var_dump($result) and see what it holds in both cases...

Comment: Most likely 1 of 2 things, either FBID is not a unique key or FBID is getting change on every call to facebook's API

Comment: if ($result) instead of         if (!$result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for `!$query` but it will always return something, so it will go the the `else`.

What you could do instead is check the number of rows returned:

```
if ($result->numRows() > 0) {
  //if more than 0 rows returned (e.g, one row)
  echo "Username exists!";
} else {
  //insert to db
}
```

Or, even simpler, do `if ($result)`, simply get rid of the `!`!

Comment: you mean if($result) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It doesn't add the same user to the database anymore (which is great) but it still doesn't print out the message 'username already exists'?

Comment: Did you do `$result` and not `query`? I made a typo! @Redlight

Comment: I have the following code at the moment:

    if ($result->numRows() > 0) {
    echo "Username already exists!";
  }
    else
    {

     $con->query("INSERT INTO USERS (FBID,FIRSTNAME,SECONDNAME,TOKEN) VALUES ('$FBID','$FIRSTNAME','$SECONDNAME','$TOKEN')");
   echo"user inserted";
    }

Comment: Ok try the `if ($result)` instead, it's easier to read and understand also! @Redlight